# Append data to vector3[] array - custom message

Tags: ros, array, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys out there,

with lovely help of ROSanswers I got into creating and defining custom messages.
My aim is to create a custom message which contains of an array of vector3(). I basically got a couple of points, which i want to publish in a single message.

So I created a custom message which looks like:

```
geometry_msgs/Vector3[] Vector3DArray
```

I was able to create a package with catkin and I'm able to use the message.

I got the following code:

...

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3
from vector_3_array.msg import Vector3DArray
```

...

```
self.stelldaten = rospy.Publisher('Stelldaten', Vector3DArray, queue_size=10)
self.vectordaten_tabelle = Vector3DArray()
```

...

```
        vec3 = Vector3()

        for i in range(0, self.anzahl_punkte):
            print 'Vektor ' + str(i)
            vec3.x = self.q1_v[i]
            vec3.y = self.q2_v[i]
            vec3.z = self.tges[i]
            print vec3
            self.vectordaten_tabelle.Vector3DArray.append(vec3)

        print self.q1_v
        print self.q2_v

        print self.vectordaten_tabelle

        self.stelldaten.publish(self.vectordaten_tabelle)
```

So the problem right now is, that self.vectordaten_tabelle has anzahl_punkte entries of vector3() (which is perfect), but each entry gets overridden by the last vec3 which is added. Just to show you an example:

The prints in the for loop show smth like this:

...

```
Vektor 11
x: -35.2332092159
y: 2.95642070607
z: 0.057369297869
Vektor 12
x: -29.4943008067
y: 3.36452718727
z: 0.0590352126953
Vektor 13
x: -29.4943008067
y: 3.36452718727
z: 0.0518744285557
Vektor 14
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: 0.0518744285557
```

But the self.vectordaten_tabelle looks like:

...

```
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0518744285557
  - 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0518744285557
  - 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0518744285557
  - 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0518744285557
```

Does somebody now what exactly is going wrong here? Thanks alot in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207976/append-data-to-vector3%5B%5D-array---custom-message/) by [Holzroller](https://answers.ros.org/users/21083/holzroller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So I created a custom message which looks like:

> ```
> geometry_msgs/Vector3[] Vector3DArray
> ```

I'm just guessing, but it might be that Python doesn't like the fact that you have a message field (essentially a member variable of your msg class) that has the same name as the type of your msg class.

Alternative names I've seen used in these cases (msg with just a single field) are: `data` or `vectors` (see [geometry_msgs/PoseArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseArray.html) for a similar msg). Using more semantically relevant names is encouraged though (but try not to tie your msg definition to your current application too much).

---

Edit: hm, just noticed this:

```
vec3 = Vector3()

for i in range(0, self.anzahl_punkte):
    ...
    self.vectordaten_tabelle.Vector3DArray.append(vec3)
```

You create a single `Vector3` instance outside your for-loop, which you then update by setting its fields, and then append to the `vectordaten_tabelle` msg object. Afaik, Python is reference-based, which means that every `.append(..)` you call merely adds a new reference to the *same* `Vector3` instance.

If you move your `vec3 = Vector3()` line into your for-loop, you'll get the behaviour you are after.

I would still recommend changing the name of your msg field though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Holzroller](https://answers.ros.org/users/21083/holzroller/) on 2015-04-27**:
Thanks so much! I didnt know about both facts. Putting the `vec3 = Vector3()` in the for loop works fine! Additionally I'll change the name though!